# Questions with long titles

Tags: discussion

All these questions have title containing more than 120 characters, perhaps some titles can be more concise:

[Will green, algae-like blooms in the side of a clear pot cause any damage to the plant and its roots, and if so, how can I get rid of these?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/16255)

[What is the identity of this plant with violet-colored bell-shaped flowers and red-veined lobed leaves in hardiness zone 8a?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/23987)

[Why doesn't the UK produce hazelnuts, chestnuts and walnuts, despite having suitable climatic and horticultural conditions?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/29848)

[How low (and for how long) does the temperature need to be before I need to worry about covering my outdoor vegetable garden?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/3167)

[How long should I wait to mow my lawn a second time when I try to avoid cutting more than 30% of the blade in one cutting?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/25302)

[What are some quick growing, flowering, climbing/vine plants that  can be grown from a container garden (USDA zone 6)? What is a good time to start?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/2129)

Comment: While this question might seem like the exact opposite of the one I've marked as a duplicate, the exact same answer applies: you've earned the ability to edit posts; please do so.

Comment: Hi VividD. I'm glad you brought this up. I agree with both parts of your concerns, and  positive action will help the community. I'll try to help with some editing.